# How can i make echo with URL arguments in ksh work?

Tags: shell, unix, echo, ksh

How can I make the following echo command work.

```
 echo -E "<tr><td style="text-decoration:underline;color:Blue">=HYPERLINK("\\\\server.site.haymaker.com\\test_prod\\sub_data\\ftp_puma5\\BETEST\\$mail","$mail")</td>$x</tr>" >> .logNamesXls
```

As you can infer from it, I am trying to build an xls file with a hyperlink. However echo returns:

```
<tr><td style=text-decoration:underline
ksh: color:Blue>=HYPERLINK(\\server.site.haymaker.com\test_prod\sub_data\ftp_puma5\BETEST\naga,naga)</td>priya</tr>: not found [No such file or directory]
```

It looks to me as if the command is trying to find the server instead of echoing.

Please can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the inner quotes!

```
echo -E "<tr><td style=\"text-decoration:underline;color:Blue\">=HYPERLINK(\"\\\\server.site.haymaker.com\\test_prod\\sub_data\\ftp_puma5\\BETEST\\$mail\",\"$mail\")</td>$x</tr>" >> .logNamesXls
```

Comment: Hi ya,Thanks for your kind response. I realised it soon after posting the question but I couldn't answer my question as I needed more reputation to do so. Thanks again!